# gRPC server cannot be built and throws error

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm trying to build a gRPC server on Ubuntu and it keeps failing at `std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());`
The whole code snippet is

```
    string async_port(":6150");
    grpc::EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(true);
    grpc::reflection::InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin();
    ServerBuilder builder;
    
    // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
    builder.AddListeningPort(sync_port.substr(1,4), grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    // Register "service" as the instance through which we'll communicate with
    // clients. In this case it corresponds to an *synchronous* service.
    
    builder.RegisterService(this);
    // Finally assemble the server.
    
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    // Wait for the server to shutdown. Note that some other thread must be
    // responsible for shutting down the server for this call to ever return.
    printf("reached here\n");
    server->Wait();
```

and the error is

```
E0722 19:54:28.324066366  257369 server_chttp2.cc:40]   
{"created":"@1595465668.324006753","description":
"No address added out of total 1 resolved","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server
/chttp2_server.cc","file_line":397,"referenced_errors":
[{"created":"@1595465668.324002966","description":"Unable to configure socket","fd":7,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr
/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.cc","file_line":216,
"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595465668.323994409","
description":"Permission denied","errno":13,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr
/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.cc","file_line":190,"os_error":"Permission denied","syscall":"bind"}]}]}
```

Comment: At the top you are defining async_port, but later you are taking a substring from sync_port. Is that intentional?
Have you tried using "0.0.0.0:6150" and passing that whole string to AddListeningPort?

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. Yes it should be sync_port. I defined both in a global.h file and I accidentally copied the wrong one here. I will try your recommendation. Thanks

Comment: Did you happen to figure it out?